# Can you explain this 6-times difference in performance between Chrome browser and Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, google-chrome

This is my test code:

```js
    function norm3Dtest(a) {
        let i;
        for(i=0;i<1e+8;i++) {
            const x = Math.random()*1e+3;
            const y = Math.random()*1e+3;
            const z = Math.random()*1e+3;
            const n = Math.sqrt(x*x+y*y+z*z);
        }
    }
    console.time('norm3D');
    norm3Dtest();
    console.timeEnd('norm3D');
```

I save it as `norm3D-test.js`, and I execute it with in the terminal: `node norm3D-test.js`; or I execute in the Chrome using the following html:

```
<script src='norm3D-test.js'></script>
```

When I execute them like that, I get a big performance difference: the code takes 6x longer to execute on the terminal than in Chrome. In my Macbook pro (mid 2012, OSX 10.13.2) Chrome takes about 3000ms and Node takes 18250ms.

**Update:** Node version v8.7.0; Chrome version 63.0.3239.108.

And here's the puzzling thing! If I change the constant `*1e+3` in the code, the difference goes away: Now both Node and Chrome execute on about 3000ms:

```
function norm3Dtest(a) {
    let i;
    for(i=0;i<1e+8;i++) {
        const x = Math.random()*1;
        const y = Math.random()*1;
        const z = Math.random()*1;
        const n = Math.sqrt(x*x+y*y+z*z);
    }
}
console.time('norm3D');
norm3Dtest();
console.timeEnd('norm3D');
```

Any idea where this can come from? Any idea on how to make Node perform as fast as Chrome?

Thank you!

**Update**: The performance difference may be related to overflow, and *3 may not be enough sometimes. I changed that constant to 1e+3 to obtain a difference more reliably.

Comment: What version of Node? What version of Chrome?

Comment: What is the difference between your first code and second code ?

Comment: The first snippet ran in a little over 2s for me in Node v4.2.4

Comment: *"If I change the constant *3 in the code"* Your two code blocks are identical. What was supposed to change?

Comment: 2422.588ms in Node v8.2.1 on my 64-bit Linux machine. 2480.769775390625ms in Chrome 64.0.3282.140 on the same machine.

Comment: No difference here either (same setup as yours).

Comment: Stack Overflow is a **very** active place. When you post a question (or answer), *stick around* for a few minutes so you can address requests for clarification such as the above.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Node version v8.7.0; Chrome version 63.0.3239.108

Comment: @ymonad: Sorry, wrong copy/paste. Now the code is changed. The only difference is multiplying *3 (which makes the code slow), or *1 (which makes Node as fast as Chrome). Not multiplying at all also makes Node faster.

Comment: @roberto: Put the version information *in* the question. FWIW, I just grabbed Node v8.7.0 and it ran the `*3` version in 2178.762ms on my 64-bit Linux machine. If there's a problem, it appears to be specific to the Mac OS build, but I'd be ***really*** thorough double-checking everything for observational error.

Comment: thanks @T.J.Crowder. I updated the question with the Node and Chrome version. I'm testing different versions of Node right now.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: could you try changing the *3 constant for *1e+3? I checked if the Math.sqrt was the reason, but that doesn't seem to be the case: If I use Math.abs instead of Math.sqrt I still get the same difference.

Comment: I seriously doubt the performance difference is related to overflow… what would be overflowing? Anyway, definitely try the most recent 9.x to get a closer V8 version.

Comment: Using `*1e+3` is still in the same range of ~2.5s for me.

Comment: @Ryan: I'm lost... sometimes the execution of the same code takes up to 30 seconds (especially the first time I run it), and sometimes as little as 3.4 seconds. The exact same piece of code... Here's the result of 5 consecutive executions in the terminal: 32444.729ms, 26475.484ms, 3250.777ms, 3259.908ms, 3261.802ms (node/5.2.0 this time). Chrome by contrast always gives me ~3000ms.

Comment: @Ryan: Now, 5 consecutive executions with node 9.5.0: 28473.111ms, 25672.588ms, 6423.280ms, 6204.277ms, 7011.793ms.

Comment: Are you running on battery? Can you reproduce this on any other devices?

Comment: @Ryan: Nope. Computer is plugged. I'll try on other devices.

Comment: @Ryan: I tried on my colleague's touchbar macbookpro and there was no difference (everything ran on under 2.5 seconds). It seems to be related to my computer then...